# How to print text file content with line breaks in python?

Tags: python

The content of my text file is:

```
5 7 6 6 15
4 3
```

When I do

```
fs.open('path',mode='rb').read()
```

I get

```
b'5 7 6 6 15\r\n4 3'
```

But because I want it to compare to string `output`

```
5 7 6 6 15
4 3
```

I want to do this comparison like :

```
if fs.open('path',mode='rb').read() == output
    print("yes")
```

How should I convert it in way that line breaks space everything is maintained?

PS: output is just the string that I am getting through json.

Comment: When you want a string, why do you read the file in binary mode?

Comment: maybe drop binary mode you'll get 2 same objects

Comment: I think it's because you read it with binary mode 'rb'. What if you try 'r'?

Comment: it's unclear if the last line contains a newline or not. This could make the comparison fail.

Comment: Last line contains newline, ok guys i ll try the r mode and let you know. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 3, `fs.open('path',mode='rb').read()` yields a `bytes` object, moreover containing a carriage return (windows text file)

(and using Python 2 doesn't help, because of this extra `\r` which isn't removed because of binary mode)

You're comparing a `bytes` object with a `str` object: that is always false.

Moreover, it's unclear if the `output` string has a line termination on the *last* line. I would open the file in text mode and strip blanks/newline the end (the file doesn't seem to contain one, but better safe than sorry):

```
with open('path') as f:
   if f.read().rstrip() == output.rstrip():
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the read mode from `rb` to `r`: `rb` gives back binary, `r` puts out text.